# Practical use of `foldl`

Tags: haskell, fold, foldleft

Today when I was working on one little script I used `foldl` instead of `foldl'`. I got `stack overflow`, so I imported `Data.List (foldl')` and was happy with this. And this is my default workflow with `foldl`. Just use `foldl'` when lazy version falls to evaluate.

`Real World Haskell` says that we should use `foldl'` instead of `foldl` in most cases. [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) says that

> Usually the choice is between `foldr` and `foldl'`.
>
> ...
>
> However, if the combining function is lazy in its first argument, `foldl` may happily return a result where `foldl'` hits an exception.

And a given example:

```
(?) :: Int -> Int -> Int
_ ? 0 = 0
x ? y = x*y

list :: [Int]
list = [2, 3, undefined, 5, 0]

okey = foldl (?) 1 list

boom = foldl' (?) 1 list
```

Well, I am sorry, but it's rather academic, interesting but academic example. So I am asking, is there any example of practical use of `foldl`? I mean, when we can't replace `foldl` with `foldl'`.

P. S. I know, it's hard to define term `practical`, but I hope you will understand what I mean.

P. P. S. I understand, why lazy `foldl` is default in haskell. I don't ask anybody to move the mountain and make strict version as default. I am just really interested in examples of exclusive usage of `foldl` function :)

P. P. P. S. Well, any interesting usage of `foldl` is welcome.

Comment: Instead of just avoiding `undefined`, you could also use `foldl` to avoid potentially expensive operations.  If your folding function exits early on a successful operation, then you can avoid performing expensive computations through laziness.  There might be more clear ways to write it (monoids spring to mind), but folds can be nice for compiler optimizations.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this. But can't imagine a good example of such a function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a more practical example using the classic naive Fibonacci implementation to simulate an expensive computation:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f a b = if b < 1000 then b else min b a
```

Then if you had

```
> -- Turn on statistics for illustrative purposes
> :set +s
> foldl f maxBound $ map fib [30, 20, 15]
987
(0.02 secs, 0 bytes)
> foldl' f maxBound $ map fib [30, 20, 15]
987
(4.54 secs, 409778880 bytes)
```

Here we have a drastic difference in runtime performance between the lazy and strict versions, with the lazy version winning out by a landslide.  Your numbers may vary for your computer of course, but you'll definitely notice a difference in execution speed.  The `foldl'` forces each computation to occur, while `foldl` does not.  This can also be useful on something like

```
> foldl f maxBound $ map length [repeat 1, repeat 1, replicate 10 1]
10
```

Unlike the `fib` example, this computation technically involves bottom since `length $ repeat 1` will never finish its computation.  By not having both arguments to `f` be strict (as `foldl'` does), we actually have a program that halts versus one that never will.

Comment: Aren't you better doing this with `reverse` followed by `foldr`?  That way you don't have to process the whole list either.

Comment: @TomEllis I'm not saying that this is the best way, just that it's an example of how foldl can be a better choice.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. Now I have some interesting examples of using `foldl` :D

Comment: @TomEllis `reverse` processes the whole list.

Comment: @JeremyList That's true.  I can't remember what I was thinking!

Answer (score 5):

I can think of one (although it might be that this yields good code only with an optimizing compiler):

```
last = foldl (\_ x -> x) (error "emptyList")
```

It would not have the right behavior with `foldl'`:

```
> foldl (\_ x -> x) (error "emptyList") [error "foo", "last"]
"last"
> foldl' (\_ x -> x) (error "emptyList") [error "foo", "last"]
"*** Exception: foo
```

Comment: Well, this is really looks like `_ ? 0 = 0`. But anyway thank you for one more example.